# URL query is adding an unecessary comma

Tags: html, url, authentication

I am trying to automatically place login data through a URL query for my university services. (https://login.gatech.edu/cas/login)

two problems arise when I try to pass a URL query (Ex: https://login.gatech.edu/cas/login?username=testingone)

1) The query does not show unless I already press the submit button

2) the Query adds an extra 'comma' to the username field... I have no idea why.
I have googled for hours to no avail...Any help will be appreciated

If you copy and paste the URL (see example link posted above) and hit the LOGIN button you will understand my problem

I am sort of a beginner and would love any feedback as I am trying to develop an app to make logging in an easier/automatic task.

Comment: If I had to guess , the comma is appended to separate the username from the password.  Since your link supplies no password, you are redirected to the login page

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried adding a password like you suggested with (https://login.gatech.edu/cas/login?username=testingone&password=1234) and again the two problems persist. I still have to click LOGIN, which is not a huge deal, but the comma is still there. That is really frustrating me. I know the password is recognized as the result of following page is different.

Thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 2):

As I can tell the login form is using a Central Authentication Service (CAS), so with that said you should be able to edit server sided files and redirect users through your application via a link, for example, https://login.gatech.edu/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fapp.example.com%2Fmyapp%2F&username=myuser&password=mypass&auto=true

Anyways, the best I can do is to direct you in this direction: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Using+CAS+from+external+link+or+custom+external+form

Comment: I do not quite understand the link provided. The link mentions editing the casLoginView.jsp file on the server side, which I do not have access to, unless im not understanding something. Also even using the example provided from your post, the comma still remains. Thanks for your reply, ill try to look in that direction but the comma is still prevalent and I am no closer to solving that than before. Will update at a later time, when I get more in depth into what you provided.